# JSF SessionScoped only allow to connect from one account to a web page

Tags: jsf, session

I am developing a JSF application where 3 kind of users(1, 2,3) can login using an id and when they login the access to different 3 menus(Menuuser1, Menuuser2, Menuuser2) depending on what kind of users they are. Each time an user logins I store its id in an attibute in a sessionscope attribute.
I want that if an user of type 1 logins and he open another tab in the browser he is redirected to the menuuser1 and cannot login from the same computer as an user of type 2.
How could I do that?

Comment: did you mean that for each user ( that have roles ) is affected a list of resources ( pages .. ) or just when the user1 will log in then he should be redirected to the page that contain the Menuuser1 ?

Comment: First of all I want to say sorry about my english. I am going to set up an example. There are 3 different roles 1,2,3. If an user with rol1 logins from its computer, he will not be able to login from the same computer as an user with rol2 while he is loged as user with rol1. Only when he logs out, he will have the chance to login with another role. It will not be never loged 2 or more users from the same host. The scope I use in the Managed Beans is SessionScope.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform authentication in `filter` , you can check the role of the user in filter class, if given role is user1, it will forward the request to the Menuuser1 else if it's the user2 then forward to Menuuser2  and so on ...

---

### Example

```
public class ControlRole implements Filter{  

public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}  
  
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  
      
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
User user = (session != null) ? session.getAttribute("user") : null;     

if(user.getRole().getName().equals("user1")){  
chain.doFilter(req, resp);//sends request to next resource  
}  
else if(user.getRole().getName().equals("user2")){
// ......
}

else{
      oresponse.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
}
```

And for  `"If an user with rol1 logins from its computer, he will not be able to login from the same computer as an user with rol2 while he is loged as user with rol1"`  this is automatically done by the sessionScope